# Matlab key events during loop operation

Tags: matlab, key

I am wondering if Matlab can distinguish each keys. I have been collecting information of that but I could not find.

I would like to use key events to change certain conditions or execute certain functions while loop is being operated. Unlike Pause function, which stops other functions running during loop, I want to make key events wait for input such as `"S"`, `"R"` and `"Q"` while background calculation is working during loop.

For example, `"S"`, `"R"` and `"Q"` means stop, resume and quit. Let's say, operation in loop is just addition of 1 to a variable i like

```
i = 0;
while (1)
    i=i+1;
end
```

I would like to switch to stop addition when `"S"` is pressed, resume addition when `"R"` is pressed, and break the loop when `"Q"` is pressed.

How can I do this? I am appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Vanilla MATLAB is single-threaded in nature.  You cannot simultaneously wait for a key while allowing a computation to be performed.  You must do one or the other.  The only way you can get around this is with writing code to create a MATLAB GUI that is designed to handle asynchronous key events.

Comment: Would [parfeval](http://se.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) do what you want? I have never used it myself though, since the matlab code I write is normally not code which is executed in real time (except for some GUI now and then)

Comment: Thank you both of you. I will check out parfeval function. If what I want is difficult to do, I think I quit choosing Matlab and will select different one.

Comment: @patrik - That looks like it may work.  Never knew that existed.